# Поиск и удаление старых файлов LINUX

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

Пишу скрипт который загружает файл на сервер и он должен найти старые двух дневные файлы и удалить их.Часть кода

```
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $DATE_FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Как в этот скрпит внедрить поиск и удаление старых файлов ?

Comment: если вы имеете ввиду удалить их на той машине где запущен сам скрипт то `find -mtime +2 ...`

Comment: нет, удалить на удаленном сервере по ftp

Comment: У ftp таких команд нет. так что только в 2 захода, сначала получаем список файлов с датами, потом достаем из него старые и отдаем команды на удаление.

Comment: Не подскажите пример кода ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203988/linux-shell-script-for-delete-old-files-from-ftp